# Generating all valid parenthesis

Tags: java, recursion

I want to create all valid parenthesis strings given an input number n. For example, if n=3, output should be as follows:

```
["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]
```

My code for this problem is as follows:

```
private void allParenthesis(List<String> result, int n){
    if(n == 1){
        result.add("()");
        return;
    }
    allParenthesis(result, n-1);

    List<String> newResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String str : result){
        newResult.add("("+str+")");
        newResult.add("()"+str);
        newResult.add(str+"()");
    }
    System.out.println(newResult+" for n:"+n);
    result = new ArrayList<String>(newResult);

}
```

And I use this function in the following function,

```
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    allParenthesis(result,n);
    return result;
}
```

But when I input n = 3, I get the following output,

```
["()"]
```

Where am I going wrong? Am I missing anything very simple?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Yes, i did ... the print statements print [(()), ()(), ()()] for n:2
[(()), ()(), ()()] for n:3 which suggests that the result list is not being updated properly ... but it should because I modify it inside the function. I am not understanding why it does not get modified after I get the result list for n=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are losing the results that you have created and are not passing it through the recursion. I have fixed it and simplified to one function. Also using an array list will mean there are duplicates. For eg.

```
Str = "()";
newResult.add("()"+str); //this will result in ()()
newResult.add(str+"()"); //this will also result in the same
```

If you want the above results then keep using arraylist. if not i suggest using LinkedHashSet as set dont have duplicates and a linked once so that the order of insertion is maintained. HashSet can be used if you dont care about the ordering of the results.

I have provided both ArrayList and LinkedHashSet versions.

**HashSet** - No dups

```
private LinkedHashSet<String> generateParenthesis(int n){
    if(n == 1){
        LinkedHashSet<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        result.add("()");
        return result;
    }
    LinkedHashSet<String> result = generateParenthesis(n-1);

    LinkedHashSet<String> newResult = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(String str : result){
        newResult.add("("+str+")");
        newResult.add("()"+str);
        newResult.add(str+"()");
    }
    result.addAll(newResult);
    return result;
}
```

**ArrayList** - keep dups

```
private ArrayList<String> generateParenthesis(int n){
    if(n == 1){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add("()");
        return result;
    }
    ArrayList<String> result = generateParenthesis(n-1);

    ArrayList<String> newResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String str : result){
        newResult.add("("+str+")");
        newResult.add("()"+str);
        newResult.add(str+"()");
    }
    result.addAll(newResult);
    return result;
}
```

You can use this function like so.

```
LinkedHashSet<String> result = generateParenthesis(3);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Good work, but if you would explain a bit more about your answer, it would be useful for new readers, and this would also improve your answer's credibility.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I was just testing my solution and make changes. mettleap, if you want it to be two functions like your post let me know and i will adjust and add it to the answer. As you can see it can be done in function.

Comment: I understand that somethings can just be done in one line or one method, but a bit of explaining makes it better for the new readers of Stack Overflow, and this I think would be great on our part. This answer looks great. Good job!

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are discarding your `newResult`.

Change

```
result = new ArrayList<String>(newResult);
```

to

```
result.clear();
result.addAll(newResult);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ... appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
result = new ArrayList<String>(newResult);
```

You are updating the variable defined at `allParenthesis`, 
the one you passed it from `generateParenthesis` remains unchanged.

Do this instead

```
result.clear();
result.addAll(newResult);
```

Comment: Thank you :) ... appreciate your help